# How can I get the certificate file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-certificate-manager

In `Certificate Manager` I just issued my domain for SSL certificate, I need the files of the certificate like  `private.key &  certificate`.

I do not see any place in `AWS Certificate Manager` console that I can download this certificate to use it in this file:

```
files:      
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      certificate goes here
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----

      
  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      private key goes here
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly you can't export a private SSL cert key from AWS ACM. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html):

> You **cannot** install your ACM certificate or your private ACM Private CA certificate directly on your AWS based website or application.

Instead, you have to deploy ACM cert on resources that work with the ACM, such as **Load balancer, CloudFront distro**, AWS Nitro Enclaves, etc.

But if you want to have **your own SSL cert**, then you can create one for free using https://letsencrypt.org/, instead of using ACM.

Comment: The reason that I need to use the way (in my question) is because of the `Load balancer` it's so expensive! and I'm using EB!

Comment: @saa As I explained. You can't use ACM for that. You need your own SSL cert, e.g. from  https://letsencrypt.org.